# Using Pods-environment.h

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I'm developing for different environments that differ in their Pods.
Say, beta contains remote logging and production (App Store) doesn't.

To selectively disable their implementations, I check for the constants defined in `Pods-environment.h` but I can't reach it from the target project.

Should I copy it as you have to with the Acknowledgements or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, short and simple the answer is Yes.
For now you should link/copy the file yourself[1].

[1] https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1068#issuecomment-18492132

PLEASE NOTE: This could change in the future, check the referenced issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is right to do, but works for me.

In your project's pch file or anywhere.

```
#ifdef COCOAPODS
#import "../Pods/Pods-environment.h"
#endif
```

Comment: The question wasn't how but rather if you should or not do it. 
I prefer copying as the relative path might change

Comment: Yeah, I didn't read the question and adding the file into main project is better than mine.